# Why do we need the meta content type tag in HTML head?

Tags: html, content-type, meta-tags

Why do we need to include the meta content type tag in HTML head like this?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

Comment: In HTML5, you can just use `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whenever the webpage is been opened locally (from disk file system), the `text/html` part will instruct the webbrowser of which type the document is so that it knows how to parse it and the `charset=UTF-8` will instruct the webbrowser which character encoding should be used to display the characters on the webpage so that it won't use the platform default encoding (which may not necessarily be the right one which would thus potentially end up as [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)).

Important detail is that this HTML meta header isn't been used when the page is served over the web by HTTP. Instead, the `Content-Type` one in the HTTP response header will be used. So if this lacks the `charset=UTF-8` part while the content is *actually* decoded as UTF-8, then it will likely go mojibake. You can determine the `Content-Type` header with for example [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), in the *Net* panel.

[image]

Comment: Also important: There is no guarantee that `charset=utf-8` is actually delivering content encoded as UTF-8 unless you've taken the appropriate measures in your application (probably database too) to ensure you don't end up showing mojibake or MS smart quotes! :)

Comment: Where you wrote *actually decoded as UTF-8*, didn't you mean *actually encoded as UTF-8*, or am I confused?

Comment: The W3C recommend **not** using the HTTP header for this, prefering instead the in-document `meta` tag in the first 1024 bytes: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's correct but it's unclear how that's related to the answer. The way how your comment is formulated seems to imply that the answer disrecommends using the meta tag and that users should instead use the HTTP header. But the answer doesn't do that. The answer merely states that you should be aware that the meta tag will be ignored when the HTTP header is present.

Comment: *"Important detail is that this HTML meta header isn't been used when the page is served over the web by HTTP."* is the bit I think needs amending, since the `meta` header **is** used if the HTTP `Content-Type` header doesn't have `charset`. Probably just needs "...in this case" and an explanation of the interaction. (Happy to do it if you like, or leave it to you if you like. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: ah you're referring to `<meta charset-"...">`?

Comment: @BalusC: It applies equally to the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the question and `<meta charset="utf-8">`. The latter is just the more concise form of the former (at least for HTML).

Comment: Not sure if the linked page has changed since these comments were made, but today it clearly states that HTTP headers have highest precedence (except for BOM). So, if present, the meta tags should not be used. Therefore the answer is correct. It also no longer recommends avoiding the HTTP header, just that a meta tag should always be used, and must match the header (if present).

Answer (score 2):

Meta elements are typically used to specify page description, keywords, author of the document, last modified, and other metadata.

The meta tag you have posted, will instruct the browser to have `text/html` type of document with character set or language set to `UTF-8`.

> Used to declare the character set.
>
> The Meta Content Type tag is used to
>   declare the character set of a
>   website. It has become recommended to
>   always use the Meta Content Type tag
>   even if you use a DTD declaration
>   above the Header. If you fail to do
>   so, it may cause display problems. For
>   instance, the document may use UTF-8
>   punctuation characters but is
>   displayed in ISO or ASCII character
>   sets. There are other benefits to
>   using the Meta Content Type tag.
>   Simply subscribe to our SEO Revolution
>   Newsletter (nominal fee membership) to
>   get the entire scoop of what the Meta
>   Content Type tag can do for your site

See this for more info:

- [Meta Tags Explained](http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-tags-uncovered.html)

Answer (score 2):

So that the browser would know how to decode the page - for example: depending on the language, the end-result may differ a lot.