# How to set utf-8 charset encoding for all views (including partials)

Tags: utf-8, playframework

I'm experiencing a strange charset encoding behavior in when developing with playframework (1.2.4).
In my main.html template viewfile (other views extend from that one) I've set a

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

But that encoding is somehow not inherited in my other views that are embeded into main.html.
Do I really have to set the  at the beginning of every viewfile and partial?

I am using eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 and my default encoding for html is set to utf-8.
Anyone knows what to do?

THX in advance
tschundeee :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following in my main.html which gets inherited by all my templates:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Are you using a front end http server? If so you might want to check that the response headers are not being modified.

Comment: I also thought that setting the charset once in the main.html template would be enough... Unfortunately this is not inherited in the subtemplates. I am using "play run" for development...

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080299/425491
Shortly, save html file with Notepad++ in encoding "UTF-8 without BOM" and your problem should be fixed. Also Eclipse as far as i know can't save files in this encoding.

Comment: I'm on OSX and there is no Notepad++ available. And I also don't want to open every file I create in Eclipse in a separate editor save it and then reopen it in eclipse... This is really strange...