# Selenium sendKeys does not work with pound symbol

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to type '£' on input field.  It doesn't work. It throws an error 'missing command parameters'

I have tried sendKeys('£') and sendKeys('\u00A3'). Neither works. However for other chars like ™ work fine with sendKeys and also with unicode

```
describe("Google search", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("https://google.com");

        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.name("q"))), 5000);
    });

    it("should enter unicode characters", function () {
        element(by.name("q")).sendKeys('\u00A3');
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you able to manually type that symbol in to the input box?

Comment: Yes, manually copy paste works

Comment: This works just fine in python when i send \u00A3.  Are you getting any errors? or any other character entered?

Comment: I am getting error "missing command parameters". I am using jwebdriver which in turn call selenium sendKeys

Comment: please add the error message to OP.

Comment: Added the error message to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200967/discussion-between-webinator-and-sureshmani).

Comment: Check this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853463/enable-utf-8-encoding-for-javascript