# Retain subscript string in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code containing subscript strings in an array e.g ["**C₋₂**" , **"D₋₂"**, etc.] In local environment, the script works fine. However, in live web server, the string became ["**C?2**", "**D?2**"] which makes my whole script doesn't execute properly. Subscript characters don't retain. Is there anyway where I could 'escape' these characters?

**LOCAL**

[image]

---

**LIVE**

[image]

Comment: This is most likely due to character encoding. (Are you using UTF-8?). It would be great if you could post a code snippet or example of how you have the live web server set up.

Comment: @JacobBlomquist The file is loaded externally. When I click and open the source file 'locally' through a browser, the script looks good. While in my live website, I do the same thing but the strings messed up.

Comment: @JacobBlomquist Apologies for my choice of words. Posted a screenshot so it would be clear to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. Thanks Jacob for giving me the hint.
As what @Domorodec suggests, Notepad is only the answer. Copy and paste your code in Notepad and save it with UTF-8 Encoding.

[image]

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50797068/8572387) for the answer.

Please do note that the character may not be look as what you've expected it to be (weird characters will be printed in the javascript file), however, the code works fine it displayed the expected HTML text normally.