# PHP $_POST doesn't take accents

Tags: php, html, post, html-entities

**This question is solved, check my answer to see the solution**

---

I'm trying to add to my DB a text with accented letters through an html form that submits with POST to a PHP page, the problem is that accented letters are converted to unreadable characters.

I have this form:

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="textarea" id="text1" name="text1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And then, in page.php:

```
echo $_POST['text1'];
```

The problem is that if i input `àèìòù` in my textarea and then i submit the form, i get this output:

```
Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹
```

My next step would be convert accented letters to html entities with `htmlentities($_POST['text1']` but i need `$_POST` to give me the correct letters.

Note: in the page head i already have

```
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

How can i fix this?

**EDIT**

I tried with

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="textarea" id="text1" name="text1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And it didn't solve it

**EDIT 2**

Also tried with adding

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

to my document's head, and it doesn't work

**EDIT 3**

I tried with setting my charset as UTF-8 on the second page too, and

```
echo $_POST['text1'];
```

displayed the correct result.

I saw that the problem is whe i use htmlentities, with this code

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['text1']);
```

I get

```
&Atilde;&nbsp;&Atilde;&uml;&Atilde;&not;&Atilde;&sup2;&Atilde;&sup1;
```

Which actually outputs

```
Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹
```

even if i set charset in my meta-tags and header too. Does anyone know how can i solve it?

Comment: You should check your encoding on page, set URF-8 and ti will work. Google it for more details.

Comment: Probably should read: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: did you set the meta tag to utf-8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Comment: @TimCooper This is the first occurrence, that I've seen, of joel's blog being referred on SO

Comment: Could you link to all relevant code?

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? Usually even if you ignore all encoding stuff, storing a textarea in a database and then sending it back to the browser should work.

Comment: The problem is the DB charset, not the page/form/textarea charset.

Comment: @EugenRieck You didn't actually read the question, as i said i'm printing a **$_POST** value when i get this output

Comment: @Harlandraka I read it before you edited it - which changes things considerably

Comment: @marinus yes: [demo](http://alessandroderoma.it/asd/index.htm)

Comment: @Harlakandra. Ah, I see the problem. You don't have an encoding on your output page.

Comment: @EugenRieck see my edits, you will see that this was already written in the first post

Comment: Your demo works for me, but you should really add this content type header with encoding. Otherwise on a different server, things will fail.

Comment: @Sven It works now because i tried marinus' solution and it worked, i'm gonna add this to my second file too

Comment: You always have to specify the encoding. Best way is to both send a HTTP header and put it into the HTML. The header, if present, is used when using HTTP. The HTML is used when loading the HTML without HTTP, e.g. from disk as a file. And forget about the `accept-charset`, it will not help you, because the browser sends forms in the encoding of the page, which already was UTF-8 in your case.

Comment: @marinus I saw that the problem is whe i use htmlentities, with this code: `echo htmlentities($_POST['text1']);` i get `&Atilde;&nbsp;&Atilde;&uml;&Atilde;&not;&Atilde;&sup2;&Atilde;&sup1;` Which actually outputs `Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹`, even if i set charset in my meta-tags and header too. Do you know how can i solve it?

Comment: Which headers and meta tags have you set, **exactly**? Remember, they need to be on **all** the scripts, not just one or the other, to force UTF-8 on all steps of the way.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld i set `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` before printing any output on my php page (the previous page is simple html), and, in addition, first html page and php page have `<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the head section

Comment: Quick question - are you on a windows server? If so, there's an additional setting in `php.ini` that might need looking after.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld No i'm on a linux server

Comment: Also, header on the html page as well, please. Right now, my form is being submitted as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: (Also, remove the `<meta charset="utf-8">` - that's not valid XHTML, nor valid HTML full stop.)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld OK added header. new link: http://alessandroderoma.it/asd

Comment: @Harlandraka: your source-code is saved as utf-8, right? Bit of a silly question, but the conversion is not done automatically. If you're using Notepad++ for the source, it's in the Encoding menu - Encode in UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld yes it is encoded as utf-8

Comment: Can you throw an accent/special character on the HTML page as confirmation? Can't tell otherwise as UTF-8 and ISO-8859 overlap for roman characters.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld if i write an accented letter from html it is printed well, but with post request it is not, check the page

Comment: I meant on the page of the form. It is there that the problem happens - or in your PHP configuration. The form is being transferred as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Ok, added accented `a` also on the main page, it displays correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i finally solved it. Even if i was setting charset, no matter if setting it with PHP header

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or with HTML meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and saving my file as UTF-8, it didn't work.

Entering `àèìòù` and then processing it with `htmlentities` was always resulting in

```
&Atilde;&nbsp;&Atilde;&uml;&Atilde;&not;&Atilde;&sup2;&Atilde;&sup1;
```

That, in "readable" characters, is:

```
Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹
```

I just changed this:

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['text1']);
```

to this:

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['text1'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

and everything worked, i get my real input printed out.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go the other way - add to your PHP code `<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>`. Saves having meta tags (that some browsers casually ignore...)

From the encoding representation that you provided, PHP is echoing an UTF-8 encoded string, while your browser is assuming that the output will be ISO-8859-1. Setting that header will make **all** browsers understand that UTF-8 is expected, provided that they had it under Accept-encoding. if they didn't, they'll barf, but I only know of one "modern" browser that doesn't, and it is about 0.2% of the market.

Note that you will need to throw that line **first**, **before any other output** (or you can output-buffer the lot, which makes life easier but drains a bit more memory)

Comment: Which browser do you think of?

Comment: Epiphany. Only applies to linux and even then, I'm not sure if it has been fixed on that point.

Comment: You do know that the HTML meta tag only applies if the server does not send a HTTP header? Some servers don't by default, others do specify a default content type and encoding, which disables any `<META>` in HTML.

Comment: @Sven: Why do you think I suggested throwing a header to not have to worry about meta tags and some browsers casually ignoring them? :-)