# Why mysql_real_escape_string doesn't work on $_POST?

Tags: php, mysql, security

This code for example won't escape the string of the comment for the database:

```
   if ($_POST['comment']) {
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['comment_txt']));
    $comment_insert = mysql_query("UPDATE msgs SET msg='$comment' WHERE user='$username'")
    or die;
    }
```

but this one will:

```
 if ($_POST['comment']) {
    $comment_p = $_POST['comment_txt'];
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($comment_p));
    $comment_insert = mysql_query("UPDATE msgs SET msg='$comment' WHERE user='$username'")
    or die;
    }
```

Why? Why can't I just escape the $_POST value? Why do I have to define new $variable for $_POST to escape it? This is security vise. I will move to PDO at some point, but at the moment I'm stuck with old mysql API.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've mistyped here. Edited the code in the question now. Thanks.

Comment: It works on `$_POST` too.. i always use the function directly on `$_POST`, there seems no problem in ur code, i think may be because of `mysql`, once try with `mysqli`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it might help you :

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['comment_txt'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

See details from here :
[PHP $_POST doesn't take accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114412/php-post-doesnt-take-accents)

Comment: would it do the same thing if I changed my database to utf-8 all together?

Comment: I think not a database issue, you have to add utf-8 meta tags. Follow the link i have given....

Answer (score 0):

That's just wrong. You don't have to put the value in the `$_POST` array into a variable before, it works directly on the `$_POST` value, too

Consider using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` though.