# Unicode characters in IE cause compatibility mode and X-UA-Compatible meta tag does not work

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a website that works fine in all browsers. But in IE 8 it automatically goes to compatibility mode (i did not test with other IE versions), and i did not care about that, because every thing seemed ok.

Recently, i noticed that if i use combination of Latin and unicode characters in my tags like `span` or `href`, it causes unordered text.

For example if i use `<span>This هست a test</span>` or `<a href="url">This هست a link</a>`, the text shows fine in all browsers except than IE. it causes unordered text in IE like `This a test هست`.

I realized that, if i turn off compatibility mode for my website, it shows text in true order. I tried using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`  and all other cases like `IE=8` and ... for automatically turning off compatibility mode,

All of them disable successfully compatibility mode, **but the page shows nothing , just a blank and white screen!** (while view source, works and shows all html codes).

Then, is there a way for solve the problem, without disabling compatibility mode ? and if this is the only way, why do i get blank screen?

Comment: Sounds like your file is not saved in correct text format.

Comment: @Teemu, the file saved in `UTF-8 without BOM` and character encoding is `utf-8`

Comment: Pasting "هست" into the search bar of Chrome switches it to LTR-text mode. Are you sure that you should be using bi-directional texts? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text

Comment: @SimonSvensson, there is no problem with all browsers except than IE 8.
Yes, i should use bi-directional text. Also `ltr` and `rtl` does not solve the problem in IE

Comment: Are the correct [character set _HTTP_ headers](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) being sent? Do you have a [charset defined in `<meta>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4696499/1615483)?

Comment: @PaulS. Yes. i define correct charset in meta.
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`