# What meta tags does HTML5 require?

Tags: html

Here it the start of my HTML5 web application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
```

Is the meta content tag needed.  Is HTML / UTF-8 a default?

I just removed the namespace in the html tag as this is not needed.

Was wondering if I can remove the meta tag here.

[UTF-8](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/unicode-nearing-50-of-web.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; typically this is simply `<meta charset='utf-8'>` in HTML5, since the actual content-type is always determined by the corresponding HTTP header instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
```

You *can* continue using what you already have, but the content-type *must* be `text/html` followed by the character encoding for it to validate as HTML5. For simplicity, just go with the new recommended syntax. See the [W3C HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) for details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Comment: @pure_code.mom Because the validator assumes you'd do the sensible thing and set it in the HTTP headers rather than part way into a file you'd already need to know the encoding of to be able to parse specified encoding.

Comment: in this case its b.c. it assumes direct input is UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct issues here: the content type (media type, MIME type), and the character encoding (“charset”). For the latter, see [<meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type). Note that there is no universal default for character encoding in HTML, and a `meta` tag is just one way of specifying the encoding and may be trumped by HTTP headers or BOM.

But the title of the question asks “Does HTML5 require content-type to be set?”, and the answer is that it does not require it to be set in the HTML document and it *cannot* be set in the HTML document. If some software parses a `meta` tag and inteprets it as having a specific meaning, it has already decided to process the document as an HTML document.

General Internet protocols specify how clients are informed of content types (in HTTP headers, e-mail message headers, etc.), and for an HTML document transmitted over HTTP, the server should announce the content type as text/html (or as a content type defined for genuine XHTML, if you want Draconian XML error processing and other serious consequences). Without such information, browsers will have to guess the content type, and they may guess wrong