# French characters in php

Tags: php, internationalization

When I get content by file_get_contents from url:
http://www.frequenceoptic.fr/actualites/serengeti-glamattitude.html

I got string in php "Jeudi, 26 AoÃ»t 2010 13:26". Characters in month is incorrect.

On html page specified:

My system windows 7.
Php.ini output: http://pastebin.com/HJvinbtm

Comment: what utf8_encode($string) does?

Comment: after utf8_encode - "Jeudi, 26 AoÃÂ»t 2010 13:26"

Comment: you should put  `<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` also your file (.php or whatever) may be encoded on UTF-8 (sans BOM)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a UTF-8 encoded string, which would decode to `Jeudi, 26 Août 2010 13:26`

Make sure your page also indicates it uses UTF-8 - see [<meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type) for some techniques. Alternatively, you can decode to ISO-8859-1 with [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), but really, you should get comfortable with using UTF-8 these days :)