# Why are tag title, meta tag going from head to body tag automatically

Tags: php, html, encoding

I have this code :

```
<?php    require_once('config.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'> 
 <title>test</title>
 <meta name="description" content="test" />
</head>
<body>
    <span>test</span>
</body> 
</html>
```

And config.php is simply

```
<?php

?>
```

Both files are encoded in utf-8 (meaning, in Notepad++, I chose "Encoding in UTF-8")

Now on Chrome, it seems that the page is not being rendered correctly. When I inspect the page, my code looks like :

[image]

As you see meta and title tags are going inside body element and I have double quotes...
I have been turning this over and over and I don't know why.

**If I change the encoding of config.php to ANSI with Notepad++, it works.**

But I want all my files to be in UTF-8...

Comment: where did the `style` element came from. you have to be looking at the wrong source or destination.

Comment: It seems it has also been automatically created. However , by the way, when I display the source code, using Ctr+U. Eveythings is at the right place. It is just on inspection.

Comment: Another answer suggests leaving out something called the "byte order mark", and make sure your server is handing the files with UTF-8 character encoding declared in the response header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work when I use "Encoding in UTF-8 without BOM" in Notepad++. I will go with this then.

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried to remove the white spaces before  ?