# how to display chinese character in HTML

Tags: html

I have created web page using Chinese. When I view the page with Google chrome, all Chinese characters are corrupted. Do I have to add something in HTML page?

Comment: As the answers said, it's highly recommended to use `utf-8` as your document's character set, but you should not forget to also change your file's encoding to `UTF-8`

Comment: Read this! https://www.inventpartners.com/news/chinese-chars

Answer (score 20):

There are two ways to define the encoding of your page. You should include inside your `<head>` tags an *encoding tag*, two ways to do that follow below:

Short way:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Long way:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

You can have more details about the difference between these two ways in this question:

- [<meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type)

If you want to see a real example, take a look in the [weibo.com](http://weibo.com/) source code [at this line of code](http://viewsource.in/http://weibo.com/#L5).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to use UTF-8 or a comparable encoding.
This can be made sure in the http headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 2):

use utf-8 character set otherwise it will all be code
remember `<meta charset="utf-8"`

Comment: Good try @justin

Comment: Thx for your encouragement

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are using the UTF-8 character set