# Display chinese character in HTML file

Tags: java, html, guice-servlet

we have one servlet program which is using the HTML code inside the servlet program i.e

```
HTML.append("<html>");
HTML.append(lnTag);
HTML.append("<head>");
HTML.append(lnTag);
HTML.append("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>");
String titalsLang = resourceBundle.getString("eayslip.tan.title");  
HTML.append("<title>"+resourceBundle.getString("eayslip.tan.title")+"</title>");</i>

// and list of codes... 

out.print(HTML);
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

I am getting the Chinese character from the property file while debugging into the code. But once the response is sent to the page, in the html page we are getting question mark ?????.

We have no problems with English characters and they are displaying correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670034/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-html should solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the editor help page so you can format your posts more readably in future:http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @ Sinistralis 

i used same concept , which you have suggest a link  to me. But i am getting the same as previous issue .

Comment: Try setting <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> to your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you're setting the content type - including the encoding - *after* calling `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()`, assuming that's where `out` comes from.

From the documentation of `ServletResponse.setContentType`:

> This method has no effect if called after the response has been committed. It does not set the response's character encoding if it is called after getWriter has been called or after the response has been committed.

Basically, you should set all the headers in the response before you call `getWriter`... and if you're calling `getOutputStream` rather than `getWriter`, you shouldn't... use a writer for text data, and a stream for binary data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I follow up your instruction . Now, Chinese character is  displaying on web page . :)