# asp.net core view page cannot save and display Chinese characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chinese-locale

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 enterprise version, and editing cshtml page. 
I would like to display Chinese characters like

### 中国China

. After I save it. It will display

### ??China

in html code. I have checked the page is in utf-8 character set.

All help are appreciated.

The code is  as follows:

```
<h2>中国China</h2>
```

Is there any view-page code setting in somewhere?

Comment: Sounds like the data field is a varchar when it should be an nvarchar.

Comment: Thank you  for spending time to help me. It's just a static HTML page to display some Chinese content in view. There's no varchar setting in code.

Comment: Are you saving this to a database table ? If yes the column should be `nvarchar` type

Comment: no.no database table. it's just a view page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, depending on your browser, set its encoding format to "auto detect/Unicode" to ensure Unicode format used.

> Firefox: View => Text Encoding => Auto Detect/Unicode
>
> Chrome: Pop-out side menu => More tools => Encoding => Auto detect/Unicode

If the browser can't display those characters properly after encoding settings changed, set the meta tag on your Layout/view page as this to declare Chinese encoding `GB-2312`:

```
<meta charset="GB2312" />
```

and/or use language attribute on html tag:

```
<html lang="zh-Hans">...</html>
```

Other way to change page language encoding on view page is using File => Save As, click the drop down arrow besides Save button to see `Advanced Save Options`, then choose proper codepage for your page (by default it sets as `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`.

Additional note: Ensure you have at least a Unicode font with CJK characters available on your system `Fonts` directory.

Similar problem: [how to display chinese character in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670034/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-html?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you. it save me lots of time.