# Adding Multilingual On Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, multilingual

I have found sample bootstrap tutorial on w3school named "Simply Me". Now I thought of adding Multilingual as feature. My problem is why do languages such as Chinese, India, Arabic, and the like don't properly render on the page? So far here is what I did:

```
    <select id="language" onchange="selectLang()">
            <option value="english">English</option>
            <option value="chinese">中文</option>
    </select>
```

and here is my javascript

```
    function selectLang(){
            var lang = document.getElementById("language");
            if(lang=="english"){
                  document.getElementById("who").innerHTML = "WHO";
                  document.getElementById("where").innerHTML = "WHERE";
            else{
                   document.getElementById("who").innerHTML = "谁";
     ....
     }
```

How to resolve this problem? When I view it on my browser all chinese letter become "????". I tried it on a very basic page without bootstrap using arabic as second language and it worked. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display chinese character in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670034/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-html)

Comment: Thank you sir, but my page had already "utf-8" on it. I also try to reset font on my body and still it does not show the letter properly.