# [aframe]how show chinese characters in aframe?

Tags: aframe

I want to use 'text' property to show chinese characters, but the characters cannot show. for example:

`<a-entity text="align:center;value: 返回back; "></a-entity>`

Comment: [This might be able to help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670034/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get a font file that contains the Chinese characters. Then generate an SDF font with [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts).

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/text.html#generating-sdf-fonts

Alternatively, the process is similar for the [text-geometry component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/text-geometry), you can generate a font set with Chinese characters using [FaceType.js](https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [MSDF font generator](https://msdf-bmfont.donmccurdy.com/) ([source](https://github.com/donmccurdy/msdf-bmfont-web)) then [load that fond in the text component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/text.html#fonts).