# UnicodeDecodeError with urllib.request object

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

When i build code like this:

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.ru') as url:
    print(url.read().decode())
```

I've got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 102: invalid continuation byte
```

What way to fix it?

Comment: Note that this has *nothing to do with Sublime Text 3*. ST3 runs Python 3, and this issue is the same in any Python 3 interpreter session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to decode data without specifying a codec. The default is used in that case (UTF-8), and that default is wrong for this page. Given the domain name, I'd expect it to be a [Cyrillic encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script#Computer_encoding) instead.

If the response includes the right codec, it'll be found with `url.info().get_charset()`; it'll return `None` if it wasn't set, at which point the HTML may contain a hint in a [`<meta>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type) instead; you'll have to parse that manually.

The URL you are trying to load does not include a character set in the content type:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.ru')
>>> url.info().get_charset() is None
True
```

If neither a `<meta>` tag nor a `Content-Type` characterset have been set, the default is `Latin-1`; this works for the URL you provided:

```
print(url.read().decode('latin1'))
```

However, this is probably not even the correct encoding; as Latin-1 works for all content. You'll likely get a [Mochibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) instead. In some cases you may need to hardcode; this looks like the CP-1251 encoding (Windows Cyrilic codepage) to me.

If you are planning to parse the HTML, use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and pass in the `bytes` content; it'll auto-detect the encoding for you:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.ru') as url:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
```

You can tell BeautifulSoup to use a specific encoding with `from_encoding` if it gets the auto-detection wrong:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.ru') as url:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, from_encoding='cp1251')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.ru')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(url, from_encoding='cp1251')
>>> soup.head.meta
<meta content="Поиск информации в интернете: веб страницы, картинки, видео и многое другое." name="description"/>
```

I must say that I am surprised Google didn't set a proper content-type character set on the response here.