# charset and favicon issue

Tags: html, character-encoding

I'm pretty new at this and I've been using this in my multi language websites.

```
<Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8>
```

However when I use it the favicon won't show and I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it.
Any recommendations how to fix it or what to use?
Thanks!

Comment: Demo of your website please :)

Comment: @Jatin Thanks a lot, I was finally able to figure it out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. That declaration will do what I believe you are trying to do with that line.

If you are trying to call a strict HTML encoding then I believe you should use: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset= UTF-8">`

But both of those lines are the same in HTML5.

There is a more detailed answer regarding both of the two lines I just listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type).

Without posting more of your html, it is very hard for anyone to give a great answer to your question.