# Why do I randomly get the string "Ã-" instead of "×" when setting button:after { content }?

Tags: html, css, less

I am using the following css to set the text for a button that will remove a tag:

```
button.close:after {
  content: '×';
}
```

This results in a good looking button like this:

[image: nice looking close button]

But randomly the string `×` gets replaced by the string `Ã-`. I first thought this could be related to encoding but if indeed it was the problem I think this wouldn't happen randomly. It happens at a low frequency and at this very moment it is not happening (will update the question with another print screen as soon as it happens again).

This css code comes from a `.less` file that I am compiling and then minifying and then concatenating.

How can I make sure the string `×` will be shown all the time?

Comment: What does “randomly” mean? After you reload? After you change the file? Sporadically while the site is loaded, without user interaction? Either way, it probably *is* related to encoding.

Comment: Try adding `@charset "utf-8";` in Your css

Comment: Yes, it happens sporadically. Very weird! For example; I just had this problem then I recompiled all the css files and hit CMD+R on chrome. The problem didn't go away. Then I hit it more 3 times and it worked again! It has not bored me a lot since this seldom happens. The problem is that it happens mostly when I am demonstrating the software to someone & it is **embarassing**.

Answer (score 6):

The [multiplication character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm) has the UTF-8 sequence `0xC3 0x97`. When that is decoded using the [Windows-1252 character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead it becomes `Ã—` ([A tilde](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c3/index.htm), [em dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)).

So, the problem is indeed that the CSS is decoded as Windows-1252 instead of as UTF-8. The CSS is normally decoded the same way as the HTML document, so it seems that there is no character set specification netier in the page nor in the HTTP header. That forces the browser to guess what the encoding is. As the browser is making the guess using any available data (and the algorithm differs between browsers) the guess can be different depending on how much of the page and related files are in the cache already.

Specify the encoding for the page in the HTML head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

You can also specify the encoding specifically for the CSS file by adding this at the top, but that should only be needed when it differs from the page encoding:

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just noticed I have this tag on my html `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`. Aren't they equivalent?

Comment: @renatoargh: They should be. It might be in the wrong place or overridden by a header content-type. There are some views worth looking at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Answer (score 3):

Try using 'ISO' value for that sign - `\00d7`

Check here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Comment: Trying your suggestion along with `@charset "utf-8";`! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you see those characters you probably just didn’t specify the character encoding properly. Because those characters are the result when an UTF-8 multi-byte string is interpreted with a single-byte encoding like ISO 8859-1 or Windows-1252.

Use utf8_decode() to convert them to normal ISO-8859-1 characters.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

or add

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

or use `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` on top of your PHP scripts.