# Specials characters UTF-8

Tags: javascript, utf-8, pug

I'm using jade template and is just great. However I have some issues with utf-8. My webpage displays strange characters like : Â® instead of ®. Adding meta(http-equiv='Content-Type', content='text/html; charset=UTF-8') was not the solution.. Any idea?

Here is my jade code :

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(http-equiv='Content-Type', content='text/html; charset=UTF-8')
        | 
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        h1 !{ title }
        #scopeDiv !{ scope }

        #small-titles<h3>Benefits & Features</h3>
        |!{ benefits }

        #small-titles<h3>Technical Information</h3>
        |!{ technical_information }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6080299/2902116 provides a nice checklist for utf-8 problems

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code, but you might want to try using character entities to display, for example "®":

```
&reg;
```

and

```
&#174;
```

are both sequences that represent the ® symbol. Browsers may not support all entity names, but the support for numbers is good.

Source:

> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score -2):

Its hard to identify your problem because you are not providing much information. I would also say that a google query could have answered your question. 
Anyway you should clearify that everything you are using is set to use utf-8 encoding (The Files, The IDE or programs you are using, ...).