# Insert php hebrew var into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hebrew

I have this code

```
$myname="דוגמא";
$sql="insert into tbl_users values (" . $myname . ")";
$command = $con->prepare($sql);  
$command->execute()
```

now if i write the `$myname` like this

```
$myname="\'דוגמא\'";
```

it works good otherwise the results in db looks ??? or gibberish.

The db and table and columns all set to 'hebrew' Collation.

Now my question is how can i do this in normal way not like this with slashes?

Comment: did you added collation `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: yes i tried `utf8_unicode_ci` still not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data Storage**:

- Specify the `utf8mb4` character set on all tables and text columns in your database.  This makes MySQL physically store and retrieve values encoded natively in UTF-8.  Note that MySQL will implicitly use `utf8mb4` encoding if a `utf8mb4_*` collation is specified (without any explicit character set).
- In older versions of MySQL (< 5.5.3), you'll unfortunately be forced to use simply `utf8`, which only supports a subset of Unicode characters.  I wish I were kidding.

**Data Access**:

- In your application code (e.g. PHP), in whatever DB access method you use, you'll need to set the connection charset to `utf8mb4`.  This way, MySQL does no conversion from its native UTF-8 when it hands data off to your application and vice versa.
- Some drivers provide their own mechanism for configuring the connection character set, which both updates its own internal state and informs MySQL of the encoding to be used on the connection—this is usually the preferred approach.   In PHP:

  - If you're using the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) abstraction layer with PHP ≥ 5.3.6, you can specify `charset` in the [DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php):

    ```
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4');
    ```
  - If you're using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), you can call [`set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php):

    ```
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');       // object oriented style
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4');  // procedural style
    ```
  - If you're stuck with plain [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) but happen to be running PHP ≥ 5.2.3, you can call [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).
- If the driver does not provide its own mechanism for setting the connection character set, you may have to issue a query to tell MySQL how your application expects data on the connection to be encoded: [`SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html).
- The same consideration regarding `utf8mb4`/`utf8` applies as above.

**Output**:

- If your application transmits text to other systems, they will also need to be informed of the character encoding.  With web applications, the browser must be informed of the encoding in which data is sent (through HTTP response headers or [HTML metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4696499)).
- In PHP, you can use the [`default_charset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) php.ini option, or manually issue the `Content-Type` MIME header yourself, which is just more work but has the same effect.

**Input**:

- Unfortunately, you should verify every received string as being valid UTF-8 before you try to store it or use it anywhere.  PHP's [`mb_check_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) does the trick, but you have to use it religiously.  There's really no way around this, as malicious clients can submit data in whatever encoding they want, and I haven't found a trick to get PHP to do this for you reliably.
- From my reading of the current [HTML spec](http://whatwg.org/html), the following sub-bullets are not necessary or even valid anymore for modern HTML.  My understanding is that browsers will work with and submit data in the character set specified for the document.  However, if you're targeting older versions of HTML (XHTML, HTML4, etc.), these points may still be useful:

  - *For HTML before HTML5 only*: you want all data sent to you by browsers to be in UTF-8.  Unfortunately, if you go by the the only way to reliably do this is add the `accept-charset` attribute to all your `<form>` tags: `<form ... accept-charset="UTF-8">`.
  - *For HTML before HTML5 only*: note that the W3C HTML spec says that clients "should" default to sending forms back to the server in whatever charset the server served, but this is apparently only a recommendation, hence the need for being explicit on every single `<form>` tag.

**Other Code Considerations**:

- Obviously enough, all files you'll be serving (PHP, HTML, JavaScript, etc.) should be encoded in valid UTF-8.
- You need to make sure that every time you process a UTF-8 string, you do so safely.  This is, unfortunately, the hard part.  You'll probably want to make extensive use of PHP's [`mbstring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension.
- **PHP's built-in string operations are *not* by default UTF-8 safe.**  There are some things you can safely do with normal PHP string operations (like concatenation), but for most things you should use the equivalent `mbstring` function.
- To know what you're doing (read: not mess it up), you really need to know UTF-8 and how it works on the lowest possible level.  Check out any of the links from [utf8.com](http://www.utf8.com/) for some good resources to learn everything you need to know.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

[See This also](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html)

Comment: thanks this fix the problem i change the collation to `utf8mb4_bin` and in the construction of PDO write charset=`utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert a string. In SQL strings need to be surrounded by quotation marks: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (field_name) VALUES ("string surrounded by quotation marks");`.

Please consider using a proper database abstraction layer like PDO or even better a full-featured solution like Doctrine.

Comment: Ok then please provide more information. What's your setup? What does the create table statement look like? Post more of your code also, for example how do you establish the database connection, etc.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
 username varchar(100) COLLATE hebrew_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=hebrew COLLATE=hebrew_bin`

Answer (score 0):

Use *UTF-8* when you **CREATE** table.

```
create table table_name () CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Use *UTF-8* when you **INSERT** to table

```
set username utf8; INSERT INTO table_name (ABC,VAL);
```

You can read in detail from [here](http://www.tanzilo.com/2008/10/13/php-mysql-unicode-solution-to-chinese-russian-or-any-language/)

Also check your connection, it should be in `utf-8`.

**For example:**

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```