# Requests module encoding provides different encode then HTML encode

Tags: python, python-requests, content-encoding

The request module `encoding` provides different encoding then the actual set encoding in HTML page

**Code:**

```
import requests
URL = "http://www.reynamining.com/nuevositio/contacto.html"
obj = requests.get(URL, timeout=60, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
print obj.encoding
```

**Output:**

```
ISO-8859-1
```

Where as the actual encoding set in the HTML is `UTF-8` `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`

My Question are:

1. Why is `requests.encoding` showing different encoding then the encoding described in the HTML page?.

I am trying to convert the encoding into UTF-8 using this method `objReq.content.decode(encodes).encode("utf-8")` since it is already in `UTF-8` when I do decode with ISO-8859-1 and encode with UTF-8 the values get changed i.e.) `á`changes to this `Ã`

Is there any way to convert all type of encodes into UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requests sets the `response.encoding` attribute to `ISO-8859-1` when you have a `text/*` response and no content type has been specified *in the response headers*.

See the [*Encoding* section of the *Advanced* documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#encodings):

> The only time Requests will not do this is if no explicit charset is present in the HTTP headers *and* the `Content-Type` header contains `text`. **In this situation, RFC 2616 specifies that the default charset must be `ISO-8859-1`**. Requests follows the specification in this case. If you require a different encoding, you can manually set the `Response.encoding` property, or use the raw `Response.content`.

Bold emphasis mine.

You can test for this by looking for a `charset` parameter in the `Content-Type` header:

```
resp = requests.get(....)
encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
```

Your HTML document specifies the content type in a `<meta>` header, and it is this header that is authoritative:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

HTML 5 also defines a `<meta charset="..." />` tag, see [<meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type)

You should **not** recode HTML pages to UTF-8 if they contain such a header with a different codec. You must at the very least *correct that header* in that case.

Using BeautifulSoup:

```
# pass in explicit encoding if set as a header
encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
content = resp.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, from_encoding=encoding)
if soup.original_encoding != 'utf-8':
    meta = soup.select_one('meta[charset], meta[http-equiv="Content-Type"]')
    if meta:
        # replace the meta charset info before re-encoding
        if 'charset' in meta.attrs:
            meta['charset'] = 'utf-8'
        else:
            meta['content'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    # re-encode to UTF-8
    content = soup.prettify()  # encodes to UTF-8 by default
```

Similarly, other document standards may also specify specific encodings; XML for example is always UTF-8 unless specified by a `<?xml encoding="..." ... ?>` XML declaration, again part of the document.

Comment: the given snippets produces `None` type error for `URL` like `http://www.uraniumenergy.com/contact_us/contact_information
` could you please say why this occurs and how to avoid it?.

Comment: @The6thSense: no idea; I don't get any error when I try it. Do you have a traceback?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I have added the traceback to the question and when I did `dir(soup)` I did not get `select_one` I fell this is causing the error.

Comment: @The6thSense: upgrade BeautifulSoup; that method is rather new (added in 4.4.0, released July 2015).

Comment: @The6thSense: alternatively, use `soup.select(...)` then use the first element if the returned list is not empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :).

Answer (score 5):

Requests will first check for an encoding in the HTTP header:

```
print obj.headers['content-type']
```

output:

```
text/html
```

does not correctly parse the type of encoding guess therefore it specifies default ISO-8859-1.

see more in [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#encodings) .

Answer (score 2):

Requests [replies on](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#encodings) the HTTP `Content-Type` response header and `chardet`. For the common case of `text/html`, it assumes a default of `ISO‌-8859-1`. The issue is that Requests doesn't know anything about HTML meta tags, which can specify a different text encoding, e.g. `<meta charset="utf-8">` or `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF‌-8">`.

A good solution is to use BeautifulSoup's "[Unicode, Dammit](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit)" feature, like this:

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
import requests


url = 'http://www.reynamining.com/nuevositio/contacto.html'
r = requests.get(url)

dammit = UnicodeDammit(r.content)
r.encoding = dammit.original_encoding

print(r.text)
```