# Google Chrome is not displaying chinese characters correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I am facing issues that Chinese characters are not displayed properly in chrome. Below is a screenshot of whats happening.

[image: weird Chinese chars]

I am wondering is there any extensions that is causing this or its because my CSS / fonts are not coded well.

I really want to fix this via my code side. Is it possible?

EDIT: Some of the words show up while some did not. 
[image]

I did add in the meta charset=UTF-8
[image]

EDIT2 : @torazaburo, showing you the code snippet. The problem is that firefox is able to display all the Chinese text!

[image]

Comment: Please show us the HTML of the portions where the display is correctd and those where it is not.

Comment: @torazaburo ok, I have added the HTML snippet. Firefox was able to isplay all the chinese text except chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
         <h1>My Website</h1>
          <p>Some text...</p>
     </body>
```

have you tried using meta charset

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

It enables browsers to understand any language it can be chinese , Urdu , hindi any language which you will write.

[image: Check out the image its a demo]

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering is there any extensions that is causing this or its because my CSS / fonts are not coded well.

It's unlikely that this has anything to do with an extension. It could be due to a font issue, but that's also relatively unlikely. Probably you have an encoding problem, so:

1. Make sure your file is saved in UTF-8.
2. Make sure the file is being served as UTF-8.
3. Specify the the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag proposed in another answer.
4. Make sure you have fonts selected which can display Chinese.

See also the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type).