# Problems with trademark symbol in viewing into the php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating a web-based using php (and etc) with mysqli database. I have created a table that contain trademark(™) data in certain column. When I import the data from the csv file, the ™ sign shown perfectly in my phpmyadmin(using utf8). But when it comes to viewing part in my php page, it show � symbol that replaced my ™ symbol. How can i get rid of this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Comment: nope, doesn't work for me

Comment: did you check **Data Storage, Data Access, Output,** and **Other Code Considerations** from that link?