# TinyMCE adds Ã characters by replacing symbols and consecutive two spaces

Tags: html, character-encoding, tinymce-4

I got a text area attached to tineyMCE tool bar (ver 4.6.6). But when a symbol from tinyMCE tool bar or two consecutive spaces are added to the text area, and after the page is refreshed. The symbols or the double spaces are getting replaced by Â.

I've tried the suggestions provided in the tinyMCE forums and tried setting the entity_encoding: named, raw, numeric. But still none of this options are working. Can some one please help?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set the page as UTF-8 via an HTTP header or [`<meta>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type).

Comment: tried that option too, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the encoding in tinymce. The encoding should happen when you are saving the text as well as rendering text inside tinymce.

In your case, the text you saved and re-rendered has different encodings.

Update your code with following. It worked for me.

```
tinymce.init({
  ....
  encoding: 'xml',
  entity_encoding: 'named+numeric+raw',
  entities: '160,nbsp'
});
```