# Browsers dont recognise Greek when trying to open html file

Tags: html, css, lang

I am currently trying to make a website in greek.I have set the lang="el".I also use brackets to code.When i use the live preview of brackets which uses Google Chrome everything is fine.When i open the index.html from google chrome without using brackets it's also fine.
The problem is when i try to open it to any other browsers.From greek it turns each letter to weird symbols.
By the way i use the Lato font-family.Tried using only Arial but still symbols appeared but different ones.
Anyone has any idea what's the problem?

```
html {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
color: #5f5f5f;
font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 20px;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;}
```

[This is how the weird symbols look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zJEp.png)

Comment: please add some of your code to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Added some,hope it helps

Comment: Nevermind just found what was missing.Had to add         <meta charset="utf-8"> in the head

Comment: If you solved your issue please add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For some languages you can just slap `text-transform:uppercase` and it will work. For greek you have to [declare the language in the HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations), so you should add `lang="el"` to the HTML tag and [define the charset as UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type) using `<meta charset="utf-8" />` .

It will also solve the issue I was having, which is the CSS `text-transform:uppercase` adding accents to uppercase greek characters.