# How to use charset in meta tage for emails

Tags: html, outlook, gmail, html-email

I am totally newbie for HTML emails. I was going through emails HTML code and saw

`<meta charset="utf-8">`  used in emails in `<head>` tags. I read on blogs like litmus and emailonacid where they have used `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />`.

My question is will using  the meta tag with `http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html` help or its not going to effect by just using `<meta charset="utf-8">` . The issue rose from some users not getting sales confirmation emails. and I saw in outlook email html source, it has altogether stripped `<meta charset="utf-8">`  from HTML of email. Is this due to Outlook where it has removed it.

The second question related to this is, is this possible that users are not receiving emails if there is a problem with only html code. I have been tasked to see if the HTML code is causing this issue for users. I have searched but couldn't find any information relating to this.

Answer (score 1):

The search term and category you are looking for is email deliverability. The first port of call will be to check your SPF, DKIM and DMARC settings, and that will address 80% of your failed delivery issues.

Wrong code in the email typically only affects how the email looks, not whether it gets there--but it's not a hard and fast rule. If emails are poorly coded, it could be an indicator of a spammer (but email service providers like Gmail don't tell us the ins and outs, otherwise they'd be circumvented).

FYI, `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />` are equivalent, but `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />` is the older and preferred way of writing it, because email clients tend to allow older style writing and not newer styles. The shorter way was introduced with HTML5 (see [<meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type/4696517)).

As for Outlook removing stuff: yes, email clients will change your code. Especially Outlook (look out!).