# How do get utf8 encoding from these simple file server one-liners?

Tags: html, utf-8

I'm doing a little home project that requires a simple file server from the current directory. I've found two good option in python and ruby, but my problem is the encoding isn't quite right. My files are `HTML document text, Unicode text, UTF-8 text` (file command)

But these server commands:

`python3 -m http.server 8000`

`ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000`

are rendering things like this:

[image]

I suspect it's quiet easy to do what I want, and just pass a utf8 config somehow. Just not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was easier than I thought, I just added these to the html:

```
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

Comment: Where do you got `http-equiv="encoding"` from? It neither exists in [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#h-5.2.2) nor [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/meta.html) and I've never encountered it in 20 years either. Also [linking `meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4696499/4299358), unbound to UTF-8.