# Opera charset UTF-8

Tags: php, css, html, character-encoding, opera

I'm using UTF-8 for my charset which is working well in all browsers except Opera, I'm getting strange characters like `€˜` instead of `'` does anyone know why this is happening as its breaking my design and would really appreciate it if you could help me figure this out, thanks in advance!

**How I'm setting the charset**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**Website link**

*[www.theapplist.com](http://www.theapplist.com)*

Comment: The `meta` tag is irrelevant here because the server announces the encoding (as UTF-8). There is no apparent problem like the one described, when viewing the page on Opera 12.15 (Win 7). Please specify exactly where you see “€˜” on which version of Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="charset=utf-8">
```

which is invalid.

You probably meant:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

But you're using *HTML5* so do it like this :

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Comment: Thanks I had it as `<meta charset='utf-8'>` before but that was giving me the problem in Opera, so I changed it to <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="charset=utf-8"> and it works great now, but do I need to include the `text/html` part?

Comment: It must work in Opera. Which version are you using? Yes, it is needed. More at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544135/why-do-we-need-the-meta-content-type-tag-in-html-head).

Comment: The advice given is correct, but it does not affect the character encoding used by the browser in this case. The reason is that the server sends `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, which trumps any settings you might make inside the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably manually set Opera to use an encoding other than UTF-8, via the View menu, item “Encoding”. Select “Automatic Selection” there.

For example, if you have manually set Opera to use windows-1252 encoding, then a UTF-8 encoded left single quote (‘), as in ‘Game of the Week’, will appear as “â€~”.

Answer (score -1):

Good afternoon! Try `<meta charset="UTF-8">` instead, could be that.
EDIT: You don't need the UTF-8! Just delete it! Really, what's the reason for you using it in this case?

Comment: Hi, Good afternoon to you also! Thanks but that didn't work, worth a shot though.

Comment: Yeah. Checking your site now to see what it could be. For me it looks kinda fine actually, where do you see the error in action?

Comment: Thanks, and I just got it figured out, I needed to set the `http-equiv="content-type"`, so the tag looks like this now, `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Yeah, as that appear to work you don't really need any help so bye bye :)

Comment: The UTF-8 is set so I don't get strange characters and I get the character that I actually want, thanks though for your time!